# How to call IAP in NativeScript js

Tags: in-app-purchase, nativescript

I have created a project in NativeScript js and want to add In-App Purchase (Non-Consumable & Renewable Subscription) But didn't know how to add it.
So can I create my own plugin for In-App Purchase?

Comment: https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase